# Why does Clang think these types in Cairo conflict?

Tags: c, clang, cairo

I am building [cairo](/questions/tagged/cairo) from source using Clang. I get the following error:

```
src/cairo-quartz-font.c:368:1: error: conflicting types for 'cairo_quartz_font_face_create_for_cgfont'
cairo_quartz_font_face_create_for_cgfont (CGFontRef font)
^

src/cairo-quartz-font.c:247:18: note: previous implicit declaration is here
*font_face = cairo_quartz_font_face_create_for_cgfont (cgFont);
```

However, looking at the source, I find these definitions:

247:

```
CGFontRef cgFont = NULL;
// ... 
*font_face = cairo_quartz_font_face_create_for_cgfont (cgFont);
CGFontRelease (cgFont);
```

368:

```
cairo_font_face_t *
cairo_quartz_font_face_create_for_cgfont (CGFontRef font)
{
    cairo_quartz_font_face_t *font_face;
    // ...
```

The full source is [mirrored here](https://github.com/solvespace/cairo/blob/master/src/cairo-quartz-font.c).

What is the type conflict here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the function `cairo_quartz_font_face_create_for_cgfont` at line 247, it is undeclared (you should get a warning about that unless you fail to use `-Wall`). So the compiler fills in an assumed return type of `int`.

When you finally declare the function, its return type is not `int`. So that's a type conflict.

Normally this sort of problem would be avoided by `#include`ing a header with the function prototypes.

Comment: Alternatively, when you are calling a function that is defined in the same translation unit, as in this case, it suffices for the definition to appear before any of the calls.  Also, and especially for static functions and others not called from other translation units, it may be more appropriate to put a declaration of the function directly into the source file, before any calls to it.

Comment: Yes, it was a missing declaration. In the header file the function is only declared if the flag `CAIRO_HAS_QUARTZ_FONT` is set. Passing this to the compiler at the command line solved the problem.